# Show white screen pages in laravel 4.2

Tags: mod-rewrite, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I uploaded my code with **Laravel 4.2** on a hosting share with settings.
When I go to the home page or any page on my website. I see a white page , no error nor message.
I set `'debug' => true` and `777` for permissions of `app/storage`
My `.httaccess` is :

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The databese was created and the tables were imported.
Please help me! My website URL is: [larintravel.com](http://larintravel.com).

Comment: That's what i see in `HTTP headers` when i visit your site: `HTTP 500 Internal server error` (which means you **do** have an internal error). Check your apache error logs

Comment: this is error that was in apache error log.443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Comment: Looks like your problem is about `SSL`

Answer (score 0):

In the past, configuring a local PHP development environment on your machine was a headache. Installing the proper version of PHP, required extensions, and other needed components is time consuming and confusing. Instead, consider using Laravel Homestead. Homestead is a simple virtual machine designed for Laravel and Vagrant. Since the Homestead Vagrant box is pre-packaged with all of the software you need to build robust PHP applications, you can create a virtualized, isolated development environment in seconds. 
http://laravel.com/docs/quick